# If I use Set I get an object required error. If I don't use set I get with block variable not set error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a dynamic button that will take the user to the correct place to enter data based on which department is listed in cell D15 on the Dashboard page. I know As String doesn't require a Set command but I am not sure what I am doing wrong with it?

```
Sub GPS1()
  Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
    Set Dashboard = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
Dim Func1 As String
    'Set does not belong here  Func1 = Dashboard.Range("D15")
Dim OpenJobsCalculations As Worksheet
    Set OpenJobsCalculations = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Jobs Calculations")


    OpenJobsCalculations.Range("B:B").Find(Func1).Select



End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try putting `.Value` after `Dashboard.Range("D15")`?

Comment: You will also get an error if `OpenJobsCalculations.Range("B:B").Find(Func1).Select` returns nothing, as in no match.  You will want to set it to a range variable then test if the variable is nothing before selecting.

Comment: @ScottCraner I did. It throws the same errors either way.

Comment: And it is that line that is highlighted when you get the error and not the find line?

Comment: @ScottCraner The way the spreadsheet is designed there has to be a match. Dashbaord to the OpenJobsCalculations the cell the code is trying to find is simple = to the one on the dashboard page.

Comment: @ScottCraner The find line is the one that throws the error.

Comment: @TonyP Since the find line is the error try the following, since `Find` returns a range... `Dim rng as range` then `set rng = OpenJobsCalculations.Range("B:B").Find(Func1)` then `rng.select`

Comment: I assume you didn't actually type 'Set does not belong here  Func1 = Dashboard.Range("D15"), just  Func1 = Dashboard.Range("D15")

Comment: @AbeGold Correct. I just wanted to draw attention to the issue.

Comment: Is "Open Jobs Calculations" the active sheet? If not, you must first select the sheet. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the Match function for single column searches. According to [THIS](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/) page it is slightly faster than Find() for single column find:

```
Sub GPS1()
    Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
    Set Dashboard = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")

    Dim Func1 As String
    Func1 = Dashboard.Range("D15").Value

    Dim OpenJobsCalculations As Worksheet
    Set OpenJobsCalculations = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Jobs Calculations")

    Dim mtch
    'find match
    mtch = Application.Match(Func1, OpenJobsCalculations.Range("B:B"),0)
    'If no match was found mtch will be an error.
    'we now test whether it is an error or not.
    If IsError(mtch) Then
        MsgBox "No Match Found"
    Else
        OpenJobsCalculations.Range("B" & mtch).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry another edit; make sure to refresh the page @TonyP

Comment: I just noticed that if I select the Open Jobs Calculations page before running the code it works but if another page is selected it does not. Do I need to add a line to activate that page first?

Comment: I added "OpenJobsCalculations.Activate" just above the .select and it works correctly now.

Comment: @TonyP sorry was out to lunch, Yes that is the correct method as Abe Gold stated you can not select a cell that is not on the active sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need these `Worksheet` object references. Select the "Dashboard" sheet in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up its *properties*, and set its `(name)` property to something meaningful, like `DashboardSheet`.

This "code name" can then be used everywhere in code to refer to a (free!) globally-scoped object variable that represents that worksheet, like this:

```
MsgBox DashboardSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

Ditto for the "Open Jobs Calculations" sheet - set its `(name)` property to something like `OpenJobsCalcSheet` and then you can do this:

```
Dim result As Range
Set result = OpenJobsCalcSheet.Range("B:B").Find("SomeStringValue")

If result Is Not Nothing Then result.Select
```

Notice how the result of a `Find` call can be `Nothing` - calling `.Select` on `Nothing` will throw a runtime error 91 "object reference or with block variable not set", so you need to check if the returned `Range` object is `Nothing` or not first.

Now, `"SomeStringValue"` is your commented-out string variable, so the full code would be:

```
Dim func1 As String
func1 = DashboardSheet.Range("D15").Value

Dim result As Range
Set result = OpenJobsCalcSheet.Range("B:B").Find(func1)

If result Is Not Nothing Then 
    result.Select
Else
    MsgBox "Woopsie!"
End If
```

Comment: I like this option. My issue is that CTRL + R doesn't do anything. Is there a different way to get to it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot Select a cell on an inactive sheet. Use:

```
Set OpenJobsCalculations = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open Jobs Calculations")
OpenJobsCalculations.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dashboard.Range("D15")` is a range, but I take it you want the value in that cell... you need to specify that with the `.Value` property of the `Range` object.

`Func1 = Dashboard.Range("D15").Value`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Assigning a `Range` to a `String` variable will implicitly cast the range's default property into a string. I agree that it's much cleaner code to avoid implicit conversions and to rely on default properties, but doing it doesn't cause an error.